# Why connect to Google Cloud SQL failed inside Docker container but success outside Docker container?

Tags: mysql, go, docker, google-cloud-sql

I've written a piece of code in Golang to test Google Cloud SQL:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var addr = flag.String("db", "", "The database address")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", *addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("mysql open failed: ", err)
        return
    }

    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("mysql ping failed: ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("mysql ping success")
}
```

I've tested the above code, the output is *mysql ping success*

Then I want to test this function inside Docker container, the **Dockerfile** following:

```
FROM golang

ADD . $GOPATH/src/github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

RUN go install github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

ENTRYPOINT ["gcloud-sql-test"]
CMD ["-db=\"user:passwd@tcp(gcloud.sql.ip.address:3306)/database\""]
```

After building the Docker image, and run the container, I got the following output:
*mysql ping failed:  Error 1045: Access denied for user '"user'@'my.local.ip.address' (using password: YES)*

I've already configured that my local IP can access Google Cloud SQL. I don't know why it doesn't work inside Docker container but works outside Docker container.

**Updates, I've fixed the issue because of Dockerfile error**

```
FROM golang

ADD . $GOPATH/src/github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

RUN go install github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

CMD ["gcloud-sql-test", "-db=user:passwd@tcp(gcloud.sql.ip.address:3306)/database"]
```

The main difference is to remove the *quotation mark* in the Dockerfile:CMD parameter, while you need the *quotation mark* when you execute the program from Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FROM golang

ADD . $GOPATH/src/github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

RUN go install github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

CMD ["gcloud-sql-test","-db=\"user:passwd@tcp(gcloud.sql.ip.address:3306)/database\""]
```

[CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) and [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) are different commands

Comment: Still got the same access denied.

Comment: I just used the exact same Dockerfile as you suggested, I still got the same access denied. I am thinking if there's something special for Docker container to authenticate google-cloud-sql.

Comment: i don't know what to say, i haven't used google-cloud-sql before, but i used database on other host than docker host, and it my approach worked for me

Comment: Maybe it's something special about google-cloud-sql authentication, I've raised a support ticket and I will let u know when I get response from gcloud

Comment: Thanks! The link helps, but my situation is a little different, I'm still on my local dev env.

Comment: I found the issue, I've changed the Dockerfile to fix it. CMD ["gcloud-sql-test", "-db=user:passwd@tcp(gcloud.sql.ip.address:3306)/database"]

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue because of Dockerfile error

```
FROM golang

ADD . $GOPATH/src/github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

RUN go install github.com/pdu/gcloud-sql-test

CMD ["gcloud-sql-test", "-db=user:passwd@tcp(gcloud.sql.ip.address:3306)/database"]
```

The main difference is to remove the *quotation mark* in the Dockerfile:CMD parameter, while you need the *quotation mark* when you execute the program from Terminal.